# Magento API with http:// not working

Tags: magento2, api, ssl

I am setting my https in Magento, and I hope every http:// will redirect to https:// automatically. I set the config in apache level

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName local.example.com
        Redirect / https://local.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

It works in frontend and admin.

However, when I try to call the API with POST method
http://local.example.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token

It returns

> {
>       "message": "Request does not match any route.",
>       "trace": null }

If I call with https://, it returns expected result.

Anyone could help? I would like calling http:// also redirect to https:// and returns correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your `.htaccess` located on Magento root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Test with Magento EE 2.1.7